# Question on Abel sumation : $\sum_{a\leq n\leq b}a_nf(n)=A(b)f(b)-\int_a^b A(t)f'(t)dt$ true ?

Tags: number-theory, summation

Let $(a_n)$ a sequence and $f$ a function. We denote $A(x)=\sum_{n\leq x}a_n$. Abel Summation tell us that $$\sum_{n\leq x}f(n)A(n)=A(x)f(x)-\int_1^x A(t)f'(t)dt.$$

Is there a generalization as
$$\sum_{a\leq n\leq b}f(n)A(n)=A(b)f(b)-\int_a^b A(t)f'(t)dt\ ?$$
Because sometime I can't take $n=0$ or $1$ (for example in $a_n=\log(n)$ if $n$ prime and $0$ if $n$ not prime. Then, I need to take $\int_2^x$ in my integral and not $\int_1^x$).

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

If you take $a_n=0$ when $n\leq \lfloor a\rfloor $, then you get your formula. But for an unspecified sequence (as $a_n\neq 0$ when $n\in[1,a]$), it doesn't work. So you have to deal with a good sequence $(a_n)$.